# why redirects from a null_session action wont support flash in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, flash-message

I have an action which is actually used as a `return-url` from my `payment gateway`. So for making it work I set

```
  protect_from_forgery with: :null_session, only: [:verify_payment]

  def verify_payment
    data={}
    params.each do |name, value|
      data[name]=value
    end
    booking=Booking.find(params['booking'])
    if booking.charge_card(data)
      redirect_to booking_confirmation_path(booking: data["booking"]), success: "these wont show"
    else
      redirect_to booking_summary_path(booking_id: data["booking"]), error: "these wont show"
    end
  end
```

could some one tell me why the flash wont work on `redirect`?

`flash.empty?` will return `true` after redirect..why is that?

But if I render it will work..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> could some one tell me why the flash wont work on redirect?

Because you are setting `protect_from_forgery with: :null_session` for the controller's `verify_payment` action.

Rails' flash messages are stored in the user's session, which you are expressly setting to be empty. No session, no flash messages.

FWIW, if you can find some other means of determining the response form the payment gateway (a querystring maybe?) you can use `flash.now('whatever')` in the controller you are redirecting to.

Comment: I didn't check this as it was a few years ago & don't have that code with me. But accepting as an answer for now. Thank you

Comment: No worries. This exact problem bit me last week and I stumbled across your question while trying to work out what was going on.